# Indexed_search extension where is the div "tx-indexedsearch-whatis" created?

Tags: search, typo3, typoscript, indexed

I want to modify the content which is marked into the div with the class "tx-indexedsearch-whatis". I searched for this div in the standard template file and I did not find it. I guess the mark code is somewhere in a .php file or in a typoscript file in the extension directory.

Where does indexed_search mark things in the div.tx-indexedsearch-whatis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DIV is prepared in `pi1/class.tx_indexedsearch.php` around line 702.

The text itself comes from `tellUsWhatIsSeachedFor()` around line 1785 and has a `StdWrap` available in `whatis_stdWrap`.

I hope this helps for manipulating the content.